# unable to perform an Ubuntu 16.04 update

Tags: updates

I've looked for suitable answers in other questions, but none seemed to help.

I am unable to perform an Ubuntu 16.04 update from Synaptic Package Manager or Software Install. It gives me this error:

E: The package linux-headers-4.8.0-54 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

E: Internal error opening cache (1). Please report.

====================

In Software & Updates I get this error:

E:The package linux-headers-4.8.0-54 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

[Sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lorzl.jpg)

Comment: Please post complete output

Comment: See attached image.

Comment: Your screenshot does not include the important information - it's outside the displayed window boundary. Please open a Terminal, run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`, and copy-and-paste the full output into your question. Remember to keep the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope it works:

Make a backup of /var/lib/dpkg/status:

```
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status.bkup
```

Open `/var/lib/dpkg/status`:

```
sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Search through the file for any reference to that package name (i.e.  linux-headers-4.8.0-54) and CAREFULLY delete that entry. Don't delete anything else. Save the file and quit.

Do `sudo apt-get update`.

This should probably solve the problem.

Comment: I did what you suggested above "sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status.bkup" and then "sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/status" but I could not find any reference to linux-headers-4.8.0-54 within the file.

I did a search for "54" and for the term linux-headers-4.8.0-54" but nothing came up - no results.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Nevertheless I ran

sudo apt-get update

and in "Ubuntu Software" it showed 1 update as it did previously, but it never updates successfully.

OS Updates - Includes performance, stability and  security improvements. 

It says it is installling but it never does suceed.